# smbclient fails with NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT

Tags: debian, netbios, smbclient

I have a Debian:stretch installed in my Docker container. I want use smbclient with my shared dir. Dir is shared on a host (Windows 10 x64). I created a user and permitted the access to that dir like this:
[image: it's in Russian but still]

I try to connect like this:

```
root@0b54a022bb9e:/# smbclient -L //10.0.75.1 -U=dockeruser
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter dockeruser's password:
Domain=[DESKTOP-SNC8BC2] OS=[Windows 10 Enterprise 17134] Server=[Windows 10 Enterprise 6.3]

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        ADMIN$          Disk      Удаленный Admin
        C$              Disk      Стандартный общий ресурс
        D$              Disk      Стандартный общий ресурс
        E$              Disk      Стандартный общий ресурс
        F               Disk
        F$              Disk      Стандартный общий ресурс
        G$              Disk      Стандартный общий ресурс
        H$              Disk      Стандартный общий ресурс
        hlds            Disk
        IPC$            IPC       Удаленный IPC
Connection to 10.0.75.1 failed (Error NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT)
NetBIOS over TCP disabled -- no workgroup available
```

I guess the issue is in the NetBIOS setup on my host. I set it in my adapter's WINS settings but still I see that my NetBIOS over TCP is enabled when I check it using `ipconfig /all`.

So the questions are:

1. Can I `smbclient`-ing without NetBIOS use?
2. If not then how should I turn it on my host?